# Health check for AddDbContextCheck by TContextService and TContextImplementation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm setup my DBContext by `TContextService` and `TContextImplementation` options.
Something like this:

`services.AddDbContext<IMyDbContext, MyDbContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(myDatabaseConnectionString));`

I try to enable health check from **Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.EntityFrameworkCore**
When I try to use this code

`services.AddHealthChecks().AddDbContextCheck<MyDbContext>()`
I got from health end point response that

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'MyDbContext' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.DbContextHealthCheck`1[MyDbContext]'.
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities+ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, object[] parameters)
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetServiceOrCreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)

Do you know any method to use two options `TContextService` and `TContextImplementation` for health check by Entity Framework?

Comment: I have created a feature request so that it is possible to register health check using db context interface : https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/14089

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to have hit a case where the two cannot work together. I think you have two options:

First is to register the DbContext directly and then just resolve the interface from this registration.

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(myDatabaseConnectionString));
services.AddTransient<IMyDbContext>(c=>c.GetRequiredService<MyDbContext>());
```

Another option is to implement the health check functionality yourself. Which is not exactly hard.

See : [EntityFrameworkCoreHealthChecksBuilderExtensions.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Middleware/HealthChecks.EntityFrameworkCore/src/DependencyInjection/EntityFrameworkCoreHealthChecksBuilderExtensions.cs) and [DbContextHealthCheck.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Middleware/HealthChecks.EntityFrameworkCore/src/DbContextHealthCheck.cs)